# Unable to use submodule in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I created a https://jsfiddle.net/5s126md5/3/

Each controller is in a different file.

Why I am getting this : `[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available!`

In reality I have multiple files and different controller

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.controllers'
]);

angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
    });    

angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('AnotherController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hola! AnotherController';
    });
```

This is the HTML :

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="myController">
      {{greeting}}
      </div>
   <div ng-controller="AnotherController">
        {{greeting}}
   </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Don't wrap the code in window.onload event handler, this way module registration happens after angular tries to bootstrap the app https://jsfiddle.net/5s126md5/4/

Comment: Oh ok well how do I make this work in real code, what is the no wrap in body thing doing?

Comment: just puts script tag in body. With onload it puts it inside `window.onload = function() { ... }`